# How to retrieve value from excel (line by line for specific column)

Tags: excel, perl

I try to write a script that able to read from excel (line by line for specific columns) and retrieve the value. Eg. Column A and Column C. After searching for days, I only able to found simple script that able to read all from excel and print it out.

In Excel

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
Dog         Cat         PIG
Elephant    Rat         Snake
```

My code for now.

```
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('C:\Modules\list.xlsx');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result: Able to retrieve column A and column C values and turn it into variable then I will use the variable for other purpose(will use it on a looping statement).

Retrieve value from excel (Below is my concept how I want to do it)

```
#Loop Start (loop through excel line by line)

$VariableA = Dog(from column A); or ($VariableA =elephant(from column A));

**select from database**
$sql = "select * from animal where name='$VariableA'";
**perform $sql and other functions**

#End Loop
```

Thanks for helping, anything u can share to me? Thanks!

Comment: So do you want the values of Column A and Column C to be stored in a variable( preferably array)?

Comment: @Praveen Hi, I just want it to be a variable. When it became a variable, at this time I will use the variable to search through the database to see whether matched the database and so on. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get you. For the above input that you have provided can you let me know what would be the expected output ? If you can explain it in detail then it is easy to provide the solution .

Comment: @Praveen I add my concept on the question. If not clear please ask me. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code and as per your requirement i have stored the values in colA and colC as shown below:

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('C:\Modules\list.xlsx');
my @columnA  = ();
my @columnC  = ();

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

#Get cell value from excel sheet1 row 1 column 2
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet('Sheet1');
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    my $cellA = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 0 );

    # Print the cell value when not blank
    if ( defined $cellA and $cellA->value() ne "" ) {
        my $value = $cellA->value();
        push( @columnA, $value );
    }

    my $cellC = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 2 );
    if ( defined $cellC and $cellC->value() ne "" ) {
        my $value = $cellC->value();
        push( @columnC, $value );
    }
}

print "First Value of ColumnA is retrieved:";
my $colA = pop(@columnA);
print $colA;

print "\nFirst Value of ColumnC is retrived:";
my $colC = pop(@columnC);
print $colC;
```

Comment: This is great! Now I know how should I get specific row. But I think u misunderstood me, I think my expected result make you confuse. `$VariableA = (Values from column A, Dog or Elephant);` << Here I only want get one value each time so I can compare to database which means either `$VariableA = Dog` or `$Variable = Elephant` . Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Okie . Then it is very simple you can push the values into an array using push function and then pop function to remove one value at a time. I modified the code just check now.

Comment: I have shown for one value as an example in the above code. If you want one by one put it into a for loop and then pass the value to database for checking.

Comment: This is perfect and easy to understand. Thank you so much!